# array_search cannot find string that begins with `@`

Tags: php, arrays

This seems peculiar even for PHP. I'm searching for a string that begins with `@` inside an array and it always returns false:

```
php > var_dump($re)
php > ;
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "@MaxyMixalot"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "GEzim"
}
php > print(array_search('GEzim', $re));
1
php > print(array_search('@MaxyMixalot', $re));
0
```

Comment: 0 is the index it's located at, no? Compare the return value to `=== FALSE`, see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

So, I wasn't heeding a warning on PHP.net:

> This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a
>   non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on
>   Booleans for more information. Use the `===` operator for testing the
>   return value of this function.

@nickb is correct:
It needs to be compared with `false` explicitly, because, if found, it returns the key, or index, of found element and that can be `0` which evaluates to `false` when doing shortcut `if ($something)...`.

```
php > var_dump($re);
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "@max"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "Gezim"
}
php > var_dump(array_search('@max', $re) === false);
bool(false)
```

So, in other words, it's found!